# Migrating data from one workbook to another, then deleting the row from the first workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have Workbook 1 (W1) and Workbook 2 (W2).
I want to move the data of W1 Column G to W2 Column X.

I want data to move provided that W1 Column H matches "No Interest" and that it moves to W2 based on the name in W1 Column A.
So if Person 1 has "No Interest" against his name, the comments (Column G) get moved from W1 to the comments section in W2 (Column X) to Person 1's row in W2.

After that, I want the entire row from W1 to be removed.

Comment: A good starting point would be to record a macro as you do this manually. Then you can expand on that code. Remember to take backups of your original workbook

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This code ought to accomplish what you are looking for

```
Sub GetData()
Dim commentsCount As Long
Dim lastRowData As Long
Dim dataRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim lastRow As Variant
Dim commentsList As Variant

'Make sure the first workbook is the active one
Windows("Workbook1.xlsm").Activate

'Find the last row of data
lastRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

'Loop through the interest column to find how many there are that say no interest. This wway we can properly dim the array
For Each Cell In Range("H1:H" & lastRow)
    If Cell.Value = "No interest" Then
        commentsCount = commentsCount + 1
    End If
Next Cell

'Fit the array
ReDim commentsList(1 To commentsCount, 1 To 2)

'Copy the proper values to the array then delete the row
i = 1
For Each Cell In Range("H1:H" & lastRow)
    If Cell.Value = "No interest" Then
        commentsList(i, 1) = Range("A" & Cell.Row)
        commentsList(i, 2) = Range("G" & Cell.Row)
        Rows(Cell.Row).EntireRow.Delete
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next Cell

'Activate the second workbook
Windows("Workbook2.xlsm").Activate

'Find the limits for our loops
lastRowData = UBound(commentsList, 1)
lastRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

'Loop through the second workbook and assign the proper values
For Each Cell In Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
    For dataRow = 1 To lastRowData
        If Cell.Value = commentsList(dataRow, 1) Then
            Range("X" & Cell.Row) = commentsList(dataRow, 2)
        End If
    Next dataRow
Next Cell

End Sub
```

Make sure you change the name of the workbooks to fit what you have actually named them.

Comment: I realized I deleted the column with the comments, not the individual row. Misread on my part, code is updated to do what you asked

Comment: Hi Trevor, thank you so much for your kind assistance, I will give it a shot. May I ask, the only things I have to rename are the sheet names? Or the column names as well?

Comment: Also, must I split the code for each sheet or this code is to be only in one sheet?

Comment: I ran it one time and it seemed to have worked, however for testing, I made a new entry and ran the macro again, and it said that "subscript out of range" with run time error "9"

Comment: Without having the worksheets it's difficult to know what the problem is. Make sure both worksheets are open and properly referenced in the code. It would also be best to step though the code and see which line is causing the error